# Ошибка в несовместимости версии Java

Tags: java, jar, version

Создал программу, собрал jar файл (IDE Eclipse), всё прошло успешно. Но вылезла подобная ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Относительно плюс-минус понимаю суть ошибки, но как это исправить или что нужно обновить? Версии jdk и jre:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что скомпилировали для java 15, запускаете на java 8.

Варианты как исправить:

1. Если не используете функциональность из java 15, то можно в настройках проекта поставить версию java8. Правый клик на проекте -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> java 8.
2. Когда запускаете, то используйте java 15. Сейчас у вас в PATH стоит java8, поэтому она используется, когда запускаете из консоли. Нужно сделать, чтоб в PATH первым был путь к java15.